# No Audio When Video Starts - It's OK After Moving the Volume Slider

Tags: mediaelement.js

Using the Wordpress plugin, MediaElement.js 2.1.7. When playing a video, the video plays fine, but the audio cannot be heard. The volume slider shows 80% volume and the UI does not show the sound as muted. Once the volume slider is moved, audio levels return to normal. So, only have you move the volume slider do you hear any audio. All videos have been checked locally and audio is good.

I see this in FF 5.01, Safari, Chrome on the Mac, and IE8 on PC. So, it does not seem to matter if the video is playing via HTML5 or Sliverlight.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got this fix from jasonthedce on the wordpress support forum, tried it and worked like a charm.

If you have access to ftp for your server, you can downgrade to 2.1.6 to fix the problem. Go [here](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/commit/e9efb92e14f599da726532ca35e03f115df09188)

Click the "Downloads" button on the top right. 
Choose package 2.1.6 and save the file to your computer.
Unzip the file

Copy everything from the build folder

Navigate to the "/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement"

Delete the contents

Paste files from the build folder

Hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

It seams that this bug came back in 2.1.9 version, but for flash fallback only. 
I solved the issue by modifying the end of `src/js/mep-feature-volume.js` file :

```js
// shim gets the startvolume as a parameter, but we have to set it on the native <video> and <audio> elements
if (media.pluginType === 'native') {
    media.setVolume(player.options.startVolume);
}
```

I just removed the `=== native` condition to make it work for flash fallback.

Strangely, I can't make this solution work when the page chunk with the video tag and the mediaelement js bootstrap is loaded via AJAX, but this is perhaps another issue.
When the video is present on a "normal" page, it's OK.